# HTML5, JS Based PDF Reader for Web App

Tags: javascript, android, ios, pdf, cordova

Well, after a lot of searching, i realy can't find a solution for my problem. I'll explain what is about.

Im building a series of apps for iPhone, iPad, Android phone, Android Tablet, using HTML5, PhoneGap.
The app is alredy coded and done, using ChildBrowser plugin for PhoneGap. So basically, i upload PDF files of magazine on my server, the app, download it and you read it on your phone or tablet.

ChildBrowser is a good solution, but for something small. My pdf files are about 15mb each, so you need to wait while it download the whole pdf file and then it will come on the screen. It is a pretty rough solution for a magazine.
I tried pdf.js but it cant render graphics of the pdf.
I saw flexpaper zine, but its too expensive.

Anybody have any ideas please?
Thank you!

Comment: can u make single single image using something like flip creator .?then u can show each page as it get downloaded.

Comment: I haven't tried that, i'll check it now. Thanks man

Comment: ok we here do that but issue is quality of image on zooming...for better quality you can cut your pdf in to smaller pages.

Comment: Since PDF.js is an active projekt, being actively developed, you could submit an issue describing your problem, and maybe they'd get around to fix it.

Comment: Well, i noticed that everthing is fine except Helvetica font. I'll submit that issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this, but one of my favorite magazines, Full Circle Magazine, uses [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) last I knew. I don't know how it works, but it may be worth looking into.

Comment: Oh yes, we alredy use a service like that, issuu. It is nice, but still remain problem of viewing in HTML5.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are Two options either you can cut your single pdf(15mb) files into number of single page pdf and load as as user request(more often load next 2 3 before user completes reading the previous page) or convert each page in pdf to jpg image and load in to web view .bot these  technique require tools for either slicing or converting pdf.

Comment: spliting pdf into number of single page, wuold be a little bit tricky to load one after another with Child Browser.
And the second choice wuold be i think the best one right now.
Html5 pdf reader are still in beta fase.